# Swipe Gesture Recognizer PFImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, parse-platform, uiswipegesturerecognizer, detailview

What am I doing wrong?

The NSLog does return the action of Swipes but the image does not change.. I tried everything I know. Help Please?

I am working with Parse.com and I have a PFQueryTableView that segues a cell to a DetailView Controller. That Detail view has a PFImageView and I need it to swipe to different Images called from the Parse Data Browser (same class).

This is my .m code:

```
    #import "BellezaDetailViewController.h"
    #import "BellezaView.h"

    @interface BellezaDetailViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation BellezaDetailViewController

    @synthesize lookPhoto, bellezaView, activityIndicator;


    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
    }

    - (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {

if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
    NSLog(@"Left Swipe");
}

if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
    NSLog(@"Right Swipe");
}

    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
[super viewDidLoad];{

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    [activityIndicator performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];

    NSLog(@"Downloading Look");

    self.lookPhoto.file = bellezaView.imagenDos;
    [lookPhoto loadInBackground];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];



    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

    // Setting the swipe direction.
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];



    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

    // Adding the swipe gesture on image view
    [lookPhoto addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];


    [lookPhoto addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

}

    }


    - (void)swipeRecognized:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe{

if(swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft){
    self.lookPhoto.file = bellezaView.imagenTienda;
    [lookPhoto loadInBackground];
}

if(swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight){
    self.lookPhoto.file = bellezaView.imagenTienda;
    [lookPhoto loadInBackground];
}

            }

    - (void)viewDidUnload {

[self setLookPhoto:nil];

[super viewDidUnload];

    }


    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @end
```

Comment: I have edited your code. Please try adding that line. Also it seems like userInteractionEnabled property of Imageview is set to NO. Please set this to YES.

Comment: thanks for your time! I found my error!! the action set was wrong and wasn't calling on the handle: For anyone who needs help on the same thing.. this was my error:

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(**handleSwipe**:)];

- (void)**swipeRecognized**:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe{

if(swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft){
    self.lookPhoto.file = bellezaView.imagenTienda;
    [lookPhoto loadInBackground];
}

What's in bold should have matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who needs help on the same thing.. this was my error:

The action and the handler should have matched: (now it works fine)

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(**handleSwipe**:)];


    - (void)**swipeRecognized**:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe{ if(swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft){ self.lookPhoto.file = bellezaView.imagenTienda; [lookPhoto loadInBackground]; }
```

What's in between **... ** should have matched.